# Object creation in a loop

Tags: java, constructor

I have a class named Node as follow

```
Public class T{
int value;

public T(int value)
{
    This.value=value;   
}

}
```

I have another class named M:

```
Public class M{

 ...//some codes here


 private ArrayList<T> List;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
 (I)   T name =new T(i);
List.Add(name);
}
```

My question is if the line (I) correct? can i make different object of a class like that as their names are all"name"? if no , whats the best solution?

Comment: Your "codes" are not valid Java. `public` keyword is lowercase, for example.

Comment: @user383240 - Are you trying for an array of objects ?

Comment: @user383240 ... you know that you won't be able to use the variable outside of the for loop scope right ?

Comment: yes , i will then add the object to an array (inside the loop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is valid, yes:

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    T name = new T(i);
}
```

That's not creating several objects "called" `name`; it's creating several objects, and assigning the variable to each one to a *variable* called `name`. That variable effectively disappears at the end of the body of the loop, so the fact that you've got another one called the same thing when you enter the loop body again isn't a problem :)

It's very important to understand the differences between variables, references and objects - and the concept that an *object* doesn't have a name; it has no idea what variables happen to be referring to it at any one point in time.

Comment: Adding to what you said, *memory leaks* is also a concern.

Comment: @Mahesh: Not here it's not - the garbage collector will be able to collect the instances created in the loop.

Comment: Thanks. I am a C++ student and hence thinking in terms of it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what your question is. yeah one variable called `name` and you're overwriting it with new instance T. You probably meant to save the variable called name somewhere. It all depends what you want to do.